# Tricky bugs in refacored pong from sfml examples

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sfml, pong

I am learning SFML by pong example.

Original code can be found [there](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/examples/pong/Pong.cpp). I am trying to put this lines in a function and then make a call:

```
    sf::RenderWindow window(
        sf::VideoMode( gameWidth, gameHeight, 32 ),
        "SFML Pong",
        sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close
    );
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled( true );

sf::RenderWindow
CreateWindow( int width, int height, int color_depth, std::string title ){
    sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode( width, height, color_depth ), title );
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled( true );
    return window;
}
//....
sf::RenderWindow window = CreateWindow( gameWidth, gameHeight, 32, "My SFML pong" );
```

And getting a full bunch of non-obvious [errors](http://pastie.org/9876290). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error tells you everything you need to know:

> ```
> In file included from /usr/include/SFML/System/Lock.hpp:32:0,
>              from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:36,
>              from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
>              from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
>              from main.cpp:5:
> /usr/include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp: In copy constructor ‘sf::Window::Window(const sf::Window&)’:
> /usr/include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:67:5: error: ‘sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&)’ is private NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&);
> ```

A `Window` is, by inheritance, `NonCopyable`. Therefore you cannot return it from a function.

A solution consist in taking a window reference as input of your function:

```
void CreateWindow( sf::RenderWindow& window, int width, int height, int color_depth, std::string title )
```

Comment: So mu function has no sense in this context.